# Kendo Entities Master-Detail advises

Tags: kendo-ui, master-detail

I come from a client-server background. I am trying to get a grip of MVC-Entities-Kendo and StackOverflow has helped me A LOT the last few weeks!

I am beginning to build a master-detail using KendoGrid ajax bind, in such a way that I can edit both master and detail. I read the examples but I would like a bit of a tutorial-advises.

I mean...how many controllers do I need for a simple master detail (1 master, 1 detail), how to obtain the key from the master, how to retrieve the detail when I change row in the master etc

Sorry it is a bit vague but I am trying to settle new things (as .NET) in my "client-server" mind :)

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine the usage of [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html) demo here for basic ajax editing with [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html) demo for Ajax hierarchy.

Basically you will need to have two controllers - one for the master CRUD and one for the detail CRUD operations. The difference will be that each operation of the detail CRUDs will accept one extra parameter which will be the masterRowID.

You need to send it just the same way as it is send in the hierarchy demo for the READ operation of the detail Grid.

e.g. with EmployeeID

```
.Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
```

Comment: Thanx! I followed your advice and built the master-detail for read.I am trying to build the create in the detail. I want to get the "key" from the master, and push it in the detail record. The Add method inserts the whole model in which the "foreign key" is 0.